# Uncaught TypeError formiobuilder is not a function. What did I do wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, formbuilder

I am using Form.io and get the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).formiobuilder is not a function
```

I am trying to build a formbuilder on evrey id what i have. So if you look at the `initformbuilder ('#fb-editor-' + sectionId, JSON.stringify(data));`. it calls the section id inside my database. And i want to that user can edit the form or add something into.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var formBuilderInstances = [];

    $('.section-inner').on('show.bs.collapse', function (e) {
            var sectionId = $(this).data('section-id');

            var fb = $.grep(formBuilderInstances, function (form) {
                return form.id == sectionId;
            });

            if (!fb[0]) {
                var data = forms[sectionId];

                var formBuilderInstance = initFormBuilder('#fb-editor-' + sectionId, JSON.stringify(data));

                formBuilderInstances.push({id: sectionId, instance: formBuilderInstance});
            }
    });
});
function initFormBuilder(id, data, content) {

    this.formiobuilder = Formio.builder(document.getElementById(this.formiobuilder), {}, {})


    if (data) {
        options.formData = data;
    }

    return $(id).formiobuilder(options)
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `$(id)[0].formiobuilder(options)` ? might work

Comment: Yea i have try it but same error. Thx for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is. Where did i found the answer on https://jsfiddle.net/h39v7tu4/

```
function formiobuilder(){

    $(document).ready(function (){
        var formBuilderInstances = [];

        $('.section-inner').on('show.bs.collapse', function (e) {
            var sectionId = $(this).data('section-id');

            var fb = $.grep(formBuilderInstances, function (form) {
                return form.id == sectionId;
            });

            if (!fb[0]) {
                var data = forms[sectionId];
                //HTML
                var formBuilderInstance = Formio.builder(document.getElementById('fb-editor-' + sectionId, JSON.stringify(data) ))

                formBuilderInstances.push({id: sectionId, instance: formBuilderInstance});
            }
        });
    })
}

window.onload = formiobuilder();
```